# Excel 2007 VBA Filtering Data to New sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How to create a macro on excel 2007 to filter some data in sheet 1 to sheet 2, sheet 3 and sheet4 etc. using a command button?

Comment: Hi Manick9, it is customary to demonstrate an attempt of writing some code before you receive help. Personally, I would used menu commands. You can probably record this macro quite easily.

Comment: I was new to VBA and needed some help.

Comment: I have figured this out already. Thanks! But I have another qn and I have posted my code as well. Pls have a look if you whenever you are free.